Use _mm_pause() or _tpause() for busy-spin loop?
My spinlock obviously has a busy-spin loop whilst the lock fails to be acquired:
while(try_lock() == false)
{
    // Use _mm_pause() or _tpause() here?
}

I noticed I don't have _mm_pause() inside the loop. I understand omitting this can cause performance degradation regarding memory barriers/fences/ordering?
Before adding _mm_pause() I discovered _tpause():
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/tpause
However, from the Intel Intrinsics Guide it usage seems slightly more complicated.
I would like to maximize performance/not concerned with power consumption.
Which should I use and if it's _t_pause(), how is it used correctly? I cannot find any example usage, even on Github.
Architecture will be 2022+ Intel Xeon models.
EDIT:
I've just noticed _mm_pause() latency is 140 cycles?!

Unfortunately I didn't see a latency for _tpause().

"I understand omitting this can cause performance degradation regarding memory barriers/fences/ordering?" yes, because the cache line is acquired by the thread frequently for no reason without a pause. This causes a contention of the cache line (and certainly tends to saturate the L3 network with trash). This can be pretty critical if the cache line is used not only for the spin-lock (false-sharing + contention). The best timings is dependent of the number of cores accessing the same cache line, the latency of the L3 cache, and the probability for the spin-lock to be unlocked.

While 140 cycles seems a lot. You should keep in mind that the latency of moving a cache line from 1 core to another is significant too, especially on Xeon servers. At least several dozens of cycles (certainly 25-90 cycles).

Oh and be aware that spin lock can be very harmful (eg. dead-lock due to priority inversion), even for performance, including latency (eg. waiting for a very-long quantum when the thread releasing the lock is not scheduled). It is generally a very bad idea unless you have a full control of the machine (eg. thread binding, other application launched, kernel configuration, etc.) and you know exactly what you are doing. They are a very common source of non-deterministic sneaky dead-lock and performance issues (while they are supposed to improve performance in the first place)...

On a hyperthreaded CPU, tpause could yield the physical core more fully to the other logical core for longer.  So maybe worse latency, but maybe better throughput at least if the other core is doing something useful, not also spin-waiting.

From this Linux patch:
/*
 * On Intel the TPAUSE instruction waits until any of:
 * 1) the TSC counter exceeds the value provided in EDX:EAX
 * 2) global timeout in IA32_UMWAIT_CONTROL is exceeded
 * 3) an external interrupt occurs
 */

So it looks like TPAUSE is intended for power-optimized sleep case, not for low-latency spinning. You should use PAUSE for that.
Also PAUSE latency and behavior depends heavily on microarchitecture, so you should check / benchmark against your real target. If your CPU is Xeon 2022+, then it's very unlikely on Skylake microarchitecture (which was introduced in ~2015).
